# Async.reflect with Async.mapLimit

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I want to gather all the errors ( if any ), from trying to save data to the collection, but it never finishes with the callback. Could someone help?

```
async.mapLimit(results, 5, async.reflect((result, callback) => {
  debugLog('Checking for repeating data');
  return HistoryModel.find({
      gameId: result.gameId,
      endDate: result.endDate
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response || response.length === 0) {
        debugLog('Saving data to history collection');
        return HistoryModel.create(result)
          .then(() => callback())
          .catch(err => callback(err, null));
      } else {
        debugLog('Data already exists');
        return callback(
          errorResponse('result',
            `The data with ${result.gameId} and ${result.endDate} already exists`), null);
      }
    })
}, (err, results) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(results);

  res.status(200).send(results);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If neither `debugLog('Saving data to history collection');` nor `debugLog('Data already exists');` is called, then `HistoryModel.find` might already fail.

I would move the `.catch` to the end of your promise chain, and `throw` the error returned by `errorResponse`, and do the whole error handling in the `catch` at the end.

```
async.mapLimit(results, 5, async.reflect((result, callback) => {
  debugLog('Checking for repeating data');
  return HistoryModel.find({
    gameId: result.gameId,
    endDate: result.endDate
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (!response || response.length === 0) {
      debugLog('Saving data to history collection');
      return HistoryModel.create(result)
             .then(() => callback())
    } else {
      debugLog('Data already exists');
      throw errorResponse('result',
                          `The data with ${result.gameId} and ${result.endDate} already exists`)
    }
  })
  .catch(err => { // catch all error that happen in the Promise chain
    callback(err, null)
  })
}, (err, results) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(results);

  res.status(200).send(results);
}));
```